# What 's the best solution to find an element in a deepest binary tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, iteration, binary-tree

Recently I had an interview question about finding an element in a binary tree. I coded both recursive and iterative solutions with C# but the problem was that in test cases when we have a tree with 1000000 nodes and all of them are on the left side. The interviewer said to me that my solutions (recursive and iterative) didn't save memory RAM enough for this case and I don't understand how to improve my solution.

```
    // recusive Mode
    public Node Find(int v)
    {
        if(v == value)
        {
            return this;
        }else if(v <value){
            if (left == null) return null;
            return left.Find(v);

        }else{
            if (right == null) return null;
            return right.Find(v);
      }
    }

    // iterative
    public Node Find(int v)
    {
      Node current = this;
      while(value != v && current != null)
      {
        if (v < current.value)
        {
           if (current.left == null){ current = null};
           else{current = current.left};
        }
        else
        {
          if (current.right == null) { current = null};
           else{current = current.right };
        }
      }
      return current;
     }
```

Comment: Neither, iterative nor recursive allocate memory in the heap. So I don't understand how they can save more RAM memory. However the recursive version allocates stack memory on each call. The iterative version needs just a few bytes to hold its local variable `Node current`

Comment: You mean binary search tree right? otherwise, your algo will not work for normal binary tree.

Answer (score 3):

Your iterative solution has some bugs in it.

```
// iterative
public Node Find(int v)
{
  Node current = this;
  // Here you need to compare current.value instead of just value
  // Also, to use short-circuiting you need to put null-check first
  // otherwise you might access current.value while current is null
  while(current != null && current.value != v)
  {
    if (v < current.value)
    {
       //if (current.left == null){ current = null};
       //else{current = current.left};
       current = current.left; // the same as two commented out lines
    }
    else
    {
      //if (current.right == null) { current = null};
      //else{current = current.right };
      current = current.right; // the same as two commented out lines
    }
  }
  return current;
 }
```